# ModX Revo getimagelist snippet. How can I search for a string in the field?

Tags: search, filter, modx, modx-revolution, migx

```
$output = $modx->runSnippet('getImageList',array(
   'tvname' => 'workOrders',
    'where' => $_GET['search'] ,
   'tpl' => 'workOrdersList',
   'docid' => 3
));
```

One of the fields is a string with parameters. How can I check whether my search string is a part of that field? I have looked up how to use "where" parameter to accomplish this task but I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use [this extra (getUrlParam)](https://modx.com/extras/package/geturlparam), you can call this instead of refering to the GET directly:

So your call could look like this:

```
$output = $modx->runSnippet('getImageList', array(
    'tvname' => 'workOrders',
    'where' => $modx->runSnippet('getUrlParam', array('name' => 'search`)),
    'tpl' => 'workOrdersList',
    'docid' => 3
));
```

This also takes care of malicious url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Where needs to be formatted as a JSON value, so you would need to define which field you are querying against and format as JSON.  E.g. `'where' => $modx->toJSON(array('pagetitle'=>$_GET['search']))`

Comment: You could also do other formats like `'pagetitle:LIKE' => '%'.$_GET['search'].'%'`